# Inserting date in mysql databate using java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to insert a row in the mysql database using Java jdbc connectivity....

Here is my code,

```
    public class DBPreparedStatement2 {


          public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{

         try {

             ArrayList<Student> slist = new ArrayList<Student>();


             String sDate1="1998/11/04";
             java.sql.Date dob=(java.sql.Date) new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(sDate1);

             slist.add(new Student(6,"James","Bond",dob,10,"jb@yahoo.com"));

             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             Connection 
             con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school","root","root");

             String insertCommand="INSERT INTO STUDENTS VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

             PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(insertCommand);

             for(Student student:slist) {
                ps.setInt(1, student.id);
                ps.setString(2, student.firstName);
                ps.setString(3, student.lastName);
                ps.setDate(4, student.dob);
                ps.setInt(5, student.studClass);
                ps.setString(6, student.email);
        }

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

When I try to run the code I'm getting class cast exception...
Some help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my Student.java class

```
    import java.sql.Date;

    public class Student {

        int id;
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        Date dob;
        int studClass;
        String email;

    public Student() {  }

          public Student(int id,String firstName,String lastName,java.sql.Date dob,int studClass,String email) {

        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.studClass = studClass;
        this.email = email;
    }
```

}

when I run the code I am getting the following error:
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Date cannot be cast to 
        class java.sql.Date (java.util.Date is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; java.sql.Date 
        is in module java.sql of loader 'platform')
        at jdbcsample.DBPreparedStatement2.main(DBPreparedStatement2.java:25)

Comment: Are you sure that the `date` in student class is java.sql.date

Comment: Yes it is java.sql.date

Comment: It's been at least 10 years since `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` has been needed; you should find some more recently written tutorial material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception comes from this line:

```
java.sql.Date dob = (java.sql.Date) new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(sDate1);
```

since parse will return a `java.util.Date`, not a `java.sql.Date`. You cannot cast to a `java.sql.Date` since the two are not related.

You can get rid of it by instansiating a `java.sql.Date` with

```
java.sql.Date dob = new java.sql.Date(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")
                                              .parse(sDate1)
                                              .getTime());
```

but I'd recommend you avoid using `java.util.Date`, and instead use:

```
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
  LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(sDate1, formatter);
  java.sql.Date dob   = java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate);
```

Comment: I recommend using this Oracle [jdbc tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html). And in case you didn't already, take the Stack Overflow [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).